# Question about canvas animation and device motion

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, devicemotion

I want to implement device motion to my canvas in the way that as I move my phone, the canvas will also move along x and y axis so that the canvas can show more image. But I cannot figure out how to do it by javascript. Do I need to create a canvas animation first and add device motion event listener to it? If so, how do I combine the animation code with the code of my device motion (all that acceleration stuff). Or I just add device motion event listener to my canvas so that it moves? My feeling is that I need to write an animation first but not sure if I'm correct.

Hope my explanation makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
window.addEventListener('devicemotion', function(event) {
  canvas.style.left = event.acceleration.x + 'px';
  canvas.style.top = event.acceleration.y + 'px';
});
```